# .NET MVC5 Identity and Google APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api, asp.net-identity

I am new to OAuth and I am trying to use the new ASP.NET Identity Membership System on a new project that requires Google integration. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to use `Identity` to integrate with the Google APIs (e.g. Contacts). I have added the linked Google account to my database, but the only thing that is stored is a `ProviderName` and `ProviderKey` neither of which are useful using the Contacts API.

How do I retrieve the login information needed to use the Google APIs with this implementation? I am aware that you can do something like below but I don't know how I would get the `username` or `password`, furthermore, I feel like there is some way to use OAuth2 to do this better...

```
...
var service = new ContactsService("My App");
service.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
...
```